# How to determine efficiency of something?

Tags: time-series

**What data I have?**

Number of causes for events, number of events, monetary value of each event, grouped by some trait.

Ex. 10,000 visits, 50 purchases, each purchase €5-20, grouped by stores.

**What I want to do?**

I want to take data available to me and extract some kind of measure to determine how efficient is each X (store).

Considering the example, there could, be three cases:

**A** store has 100 visits, 10 sales, each €5;

**B** store has 50 visits, 40 sales, each €20;

**C** store has 5000 visits, 40 sales, each €20;

clearly, **B** is more efficient - while having less visits, it clearly made the most revenues.

**What is the goal?**

I would like to have some sort of metric which I can store and evaluate against progression of time (B was more effective last week, than it is today).

**What is the question?**

Given these metrics, how can I calculate one something that can be stored and compared over time and against other groupings?

For example, can I have a magic number of sorts derived from these metrics that I can later just compare against between two stores and between the same store in time series? How?

**EDIT 1:** one something that I can do is calculate, for example, sum of sales per 1000 visits and then compare that - like some kind of CPM metric. I guess that could do?

**EDIT 2:** So far I went for

`(sum of sales / (number of visits / 1000))`

which gives me a sort of "value per mille" measure that

1. is comparable between the time-series of same group;
2. is comparable between time-series of different groups;
3. gives an insight of the actual throughput performance - higher value per mille = better;

Not a perfect solution that accounts for ratio of sales against visits, but good enough. Can this be improved to account for that?

*Sidenote:* I am fairly confident that 99% of the stuff in the CV, beyond Pearson's and chi-squared, is Voodoo and black magic. Dumb it down, if you can.

Comment: What's "the CW"?

Comment: @Scortchi ... *CV - cross validated...

Answer (score 2):

You might consider (Sales/Visits)*Price. Which would give you average money earned per visit. I always prefer to calculate such things in real units and this would provide a measure of efficiency in easy to interpret units.

Comment: Problem with this, as I pointed out in the question, price is a variable value - averaging it would not be very precise. Could you maybe explain your formula a bit further?

Comment: I don't understand the import of this comment, Matiss, because `Sales` and `Visits` are also "variable values." This proposal by Rlandrith certainly is consistent with what you are looking for.  The problem is that you don't give any clear sense of "efficiency" that could distinguish this formula from infinitely many other formulas that are also consistent with your question. Since we can't make infinitely many guesses about what would please you, I think *you* would be the proper person to do more explaining--by editing your post.

Comment: @whuber I believe variable value means that the value, well, is variable - e.g. there is no "Price", there can be "sum of Prices" or "average of Prices". As for the efficiency, the standard definition applies - "the ratio of the useful work performed in a process to the total energy expended", expressed as any meaningful value that fits the requirements of the question. I am not a statistician nor data scientist - if you have a specific question to ask - do so. If your goal is to be condescending and to have a philosophical debate about concept of infinity - I see no value in that at all.

Comment: You seem confused about how this site works, Matiss: it is you who came here with a question, not I.  My role is to help you use the site effectively.  Your comment appears to have fully answered your own question, leaving me wondering what it is you are hoping for in terms of answers.

Comment: I understand perfectly well how this site works, @whuber - I came with a question based on what I could reasonably believe could be enough to solve the problem. If you are a professional in the field and it is obvious for you that I have missed something or formulated something wrong, point it out and I will attempt to correct that as much as I can. I still don't see how this answer solves my problem, hence I asked OP to elaborate - how does this work and why? Or am I gravely mistaken and this part of stackexchange is for field professionals and academics exclusively?

Comment: Matiss, this site is for *anyone* who is willing to respond constructively to comments and work to refine and clarify their questions.

Comment: @whuber are you implying I am not?